# Generic linear subspaces of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, incidence-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the real vector space of symmetric $n\times n$ traceless matrices with real entries and let $L\subset \mathcal{S}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear subspace.  Noticing that every matrix $A\in L$ is diagonalizable,
suppose that for all non-zero $A\in L,$ the matrix $A$ has distinct eigenvalues.

**Question:**  What is the optimal upper bound on the dimension of the real vector space $L?$

There is an obvious upper bound which follows from the following observation (I'll omit the numbers to be brief).  Let $\Delta\subset \mathcal{S}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the $(n-1)$-dimensional linear subspace of diagonal matrices.
Then, we must have that $L\cap \Delta$ has dimension at most one.  Moreover, there is nothing special about $\Delta,$ given any $g\in SO(n),$ it also needs to be true that $L\cap (g\cdot \Delta\cdot g^{-1})$ has dimension at most one.  This latter condition leads to an equivalent reformulation of the question.

**Question:** Suppose for every $g\in SO(n),$ the intersection $L\cap (g\cdot \Delta\cdot g^{-1})$ has dimension at most one.  What is the optimal upper bound on the dimension of $L?$

For Lie-theoretic minded people, there is an obvious generalization of this question. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a real (semi)-simple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus \mathfrak{m}$ a Cartan decomposition.  Let $L\subset \mathfrak{m}$ be a linear subspace, and suppose that for any non-zero $X\in L,$ the vector $X$ is regular.  By regular, I mean that $X$ belongs to a unique Cartan subspace $\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathfrak{m}.$  Then the question is again, how big can the dimension of $L$ be?

Comment: It might be useful to give a name, say $b(n)$, to the integer defined by the question. The observation on intersection with $\Delta$ gives $b(n)\le n(n+1)/2-1- (n-2)$, and $b(2)=2$.

Comment: (I'm not sure why the word "generic" is used in the question: this is not about generic subspaces.)

Comment: @YCor, I'm not convinced naming the integer really adds anything to question, and given your comment, it should be clear to readers.  As to your second comment, the title should really include "linear subspaces all of whose elements are generic," but I couldn't figure out how to say this without sounding long-winded.

Comment: In any case so far I only see $b(n)\ge 2$ for $n$ even and $b(n)\ge 1$ for $n$ odd. Any better lower bound? Do you know what is $b(3)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: There are much larger subspaces all whose elements have two equal eigenvalues --- say, the matrices where the first two rows vanish (you may also replace the  $(1,1)$th and $(2,2)$th entries by two equal numbers). So the answer to the first question does nor exceed $2n-1$.